# wrong ip in vagrant machine

Tags: ip, vagrant, vagrantfile

This is my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"


    config.vm.define "test_mashine", primary: true do |test_mashine|
               # ...
               config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
               test_mashine.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10", bridge: "eth0"
               config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
                       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
               end
    end

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

end
```

This is ping statistic:

```
ping 192.168.33.10
PING 192.168.33.10 (192.168.33.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.560 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.179 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.205 ms
^C
--- 192.168.33.10 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.179/0.284/0.560/0.159 ms
```

when i do vagrant ssh -c"ifconfig":

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef6:b007  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f6:b0:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 483  bytes 54593 (53.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 299  bytes 44693 (43.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe17:2deb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:17:2d:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7  bytes 1632 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 2090 (2.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

The ip address of machine is 192.168.56.109. Ip address must be 192.168.33.10. When I start machine with ip 192.168.101.100 - ip sets right.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

why your doing bridge ?
if you want to give private ip then you should give like:

```
test_mashine.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
```

if you want to give ip from public subnet then you have to give like:

```
test_mashine.vm.network "public_network"
```

or for static you can give `IP` or `bridge` name also.

your `Vagrantfile` should be like:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

# config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"

    config.vm.define :test_mashine do |test_mashine|
               # ...
               test_mashine.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
               test_mashine.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
               test_mashine.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
                       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
               end
    end

  config.ssh.insert_key = false

end
```

For more info refer [Vagrant Networking](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/)

Comment: I have upped my machine with your configuration but it still does not work ip now is: inet 192.168.56.112  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255

Comment: what step you followed. run command `vagrant reload`. it will reflect vagrantfile change to vm. or destroy `vagrant destroy test_mashine` and create new one `vagrant up test_mashine`.

Comment: when I have done `vagrant destroy test_mashine` then `vagrant up test_mashine` ip was `inet 192.168.56.112 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.56.255` but when I have done `vagrant reaload test_machine` ip was `inet 192.168.33.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255`. But it does not solve my problem, I must do reload always after upping.

Comment: no, i think you missed something.  if it is working with reload then it should come with `vagrant up` as well. can you try from scratch. config is ok .try again.